# HTML templating engine unable to render unicode symbols

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, nunjucks, templating-engine

I'm attempting to dynamically render some data on a page using nunjucks as a templating engine.

For certain parts of my data, I need unicode symbols to be rendered e.g. ✔︎

I've tried passing in the actual code (&#x2714;) for the symbol to my HTML template but it just renders as &#x2714; rather than the actual symbol (✔). I assume this is happening because it's getting sent as a string.

Is there a way around this? Maybe something related to escaping characters.

I'm using JS as my server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the way to do this is to use the safe filter as such - `{{ value | safe }}`